# How to iterate gremlinepipeline of titan db to get the vertex & it's properties in Java API

Tags: titan, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

Here is the sample code which I am using but I don't know how to use this Pipeline object to get the vertices & it's properties.

```
GremlinPipeline pipeline = new GremlinPipeline(vert)
  .out("LIVES_IN_CITY").in("LIVES_IN_CITY")
  .filter(new PipeFunction<Vertex,Boolean>() {
            public Boolean compute(Vertex v){
                  return v.getProperty("name").equals(city);     
  }}).back(2).out("LIVES_IN_CITY");
```

Comment: I don't really follow what you are asking.  Could you please reform your question?  Are you asking how to get a "result" from the pipeline you have shown in your sample code?

Comment: vert is the employee node which is start node & LIVES_IN_CITY is the edge from employee node towards city node. I want to find out who are other employee lives in the same city. gremline query could be : g.V.('id',1234).out('LIVES_IN_CITY').inE.outV                                                         TO get the above result, i am using gremlinepipeline java api but i am not able to iterate properly & get the result. Please suggest me how to achieve the above result.

Answer (score 1):

A Gremlin `Pipeline` is just an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) - so treat it as such.  At a low level, use a `while` loop to iterate checking `hasNext()` to see if there are more items in the pipeline to extract and use `next` to pop off the very next item in the `Iterator`.

`Pipeline` also has `toList()` and `fill()` methods to work at a higher level of abstraction.  You can see the API [here](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/pipes/2.6.0/com/tinkerpop/pipes/util/Pipeline.html).

Comment: I tried to iterate but getting classcast exception  : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge

Comment: Are you executing the same pipeline code you have in your question? i'm not seeing how you get that exception given that block of code.

Comment: For above block of code, i am getting -  com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.FastNoSuchElementException. I have made some changes in the above code mentioned below & got the ClassCastException which i have mentioned in my 1st comment.                                                                 GremlinPipeline pipe1 = new GremlinPipeline(vert).out("LIVES_IN_CITY").as("x").inV().filter(new PipeFunction<Vertex,Boolean>() {
   public Boolean compute(Vertex v){
    System.out.println("pass ho rha hai");
       return v.getProperty("name").equals("HOUSTON");
       }
    }).back(2).out("LIVES_IN_CITY");

Comment: If you have a `FastNoSuchElementException` then there is no data in your pipeline, which might mean in your case that you have a bug in your traversal or your test data is incomplete.  As for the `ClassCastException`, you are doing an `inV` from the `out('LIVES_IN_CITY')` step.  Since `out` returns a `Vertex`, you can try to do an `inV` on it as that is a step for an `Edge`.